# Quoting Class Name in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Is there any difference between passing a constant or a quoted string to rspec for the class name?

Constant:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Match do
end
```

Quote:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Match" do
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `describe` is the description of that example group. However, per https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject:

> If the first argument to the outermost example group is a class, an
>   instance of that class is exposed to each example via the subject
>   method.

It also adds:

> While the examples below demonstrate how subject can be used as a
>   user-facing concept, we recommend that you reserve it for support of
>   custom matchers and/or extension libraries that hide its use from
>   examples.

The rules of behavior are a little more complicated than implied above, however, at least as of RSpec 2.99. For example, non-class arguments are still exposed via the subject method, but the innermost example group takes precedence. In adition, the rule about instantiating a class will apply even if it's not the outermost example group.

The following passing examples illustrate more of the cases:

```
# simple case for class
describe Object do
  specify {subject.should be_an_instance_of(Object)}
end

# simple case for non-class
describe "String" do
  specify {subject.should be_eql("String")}
end

# nested non-class arguments; inner takes precedence
describe "Outer String" do
  describe "String" do
    specify {subject.should be_eql("String")}
  end
end

# nested class arguments; outer takes precedence
describe Object do
  describe Module do
    specify {subject.should be_an_instance_of(Object)}
  end
end

# class inside non-class; class takes precedence
describe "String" do
  describe Object do
    specify {subject.should be_an_instance_of(Object)}
  end
end

# class inside explicit subject; explicit subject takes precedence
describe "Outer string" do
  subject {"String"}
  describe Object do
    specify {subject.should be_eql("String")}
  end
end

# class outside explicit subject; explicit subject takes precedence
describe Object do
  subject {"String"}
  describe Module do
    specify {subject.should be_eql("String")}
  end
end
```